# Troubles GETting reply from server using retrofit

Tags: android, get, retrofit, cloudsight

I'm trying to get a reply from a server for an android app using retrofit. I manage to send the request no problem, but the callback seems to always be null, also it seems to never either fail or succeed, which sounds very strange.
Something else which I don't understand is that the retrofit Log does show a response, but the callback variables don't seem to get them?!

I'm meant to poll the server every few seconds to check if something has changed, I'm not sure how to do this so I've tried simply sending the request over and over again but no luck, and using Observable doesn't seem to work either, so I'm just going with a asynchronous callback (synchronous would be fine but android seems not to like it very much).

Here are some parts of the code that might be of use :
the get interface :

```
interface CamFindGet {
    @Headers("Authorization: CloudSight XXX")
    @GET("/image_responses/{token}")
    void getResult(@Path("token") String token,
                   Callback<resultClassGet> callback);}
```

the rest adapter :

```
final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                @Override
                public void log(String msg) {
                    String[] blacklist = {"Access-Control", "Cache-Control", "Connection", "Content-Type", "Keep-Alive", "Pragma", "Server", "Vary", "X-Powered-By"};
                    for (String bString : blacklist) {
                        if (msg.startsWith(bString)) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("Retrofit", msg);
                }
            }).build();

CamFindGet camFindGet = restAdapter.create(CamFindGet.class);

                try { //NOTE : result.getToken() is a valid token
                    getCamResult(camFindGet, result.getToken());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The actual GET request :

```
static void getCamResult(CamFindGet camFindGet, String token) throws InterruptedException {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET CAM RESULT");


        Log.d(TAG, "LOOP");
        camFindGet.getResult(token, new Callback<resultClassGet>() {
            @Override
            public void success(resultClassGet resultClass, Response response) {
                //Log.d(TAG, resultClass.getName());

                if (resultClass.getStatus().equals("completed") || resultClass.getStatus().equals("not found"))
                    completedGet = 1;

                if(completedGet==1) {
                    resultString = new String(resultClass.getName());
                    Log.d(TAG, "RESULT : "+resultString);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, resultClass.getStatus());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Log.d(TAG, retrofitError.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILURE?");
            }
        });

}
```

and finally, the log :

```
07-01 17:20:23.838    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_responses/dUYO5-77ETRJx4bzjL6LEw
07-01 17:20:23.838    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ Authorization: CloudSight XXX
07-01 17:20:23.840    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_responses/dUYO5-77ETRJx4bzjL6LEw (143ms)
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 52
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 17:20:35 GMT
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ ETag: "d5143f21b04e73bd70aa104b52ea7bb7"
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ Set-Cookie: _imagetag_session=dDE1R1lCQ2xUa0VxOUxXZTNKVzdraHIxNW9UOGpKaGpEVHdwSmhtb1NoSU5Jc2htbUVtZGI0Q2Flc1RZMmtadWZQMnRpTkI3L1ZveFlhaFlrZjY2RHc9PS0tdHZVMGxpcDRjbkF5THlxYlB0MjdUQT09--24783a1b51c595beeb955ac9e860498ad8e7c7cb; path=/; HttpOnly
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Android-Received-Millis: 1435771223983
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1435771223840
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Request-Id: 327b11e7-8f38-431b-97bb-3f1d1738395f
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-Runtime: 0.044161
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
07-01 17:20:23.984    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ [ 07-01 17:20:23.985  4626: 4650 D/Retrofit ]{"status":"completed","name":"green square drawing"}
07-01 17:20:23.985    4626-4650/app D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (52-byte body)
```

NOTE : for both success, some LOG should appear in the debug (either `FAILURE`? or `get.status()` but neither does)

EDIT : I might be onto something, apparently for asynchronous requests you need to have a `.setExecutors()` in the rest adapter creation, I'm trying to understand how would that work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, just had to create an executor this way :

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

And then when making the rest adapter, add the setExecutors line :

```
 RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint(API_URL);
    builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
    builder.setExecutors(executor, null); //<<-- this line
    builder.setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
        @Override
        public void log(String msg) {
            String[] blacklist = {"Access-Control", "Cache-Control", "Connection", "Content-Type", "Keep-Alive", "Pragma", "Server", "Vary", "X-Powered-By"};
            for (String bString : blacklist) {
                if (msg.startsWith(bString)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Log.d("Retrofit", msg);
        }
    });
```